# I invented <tf> element for table and now the row jump on top? How to fix?

Tags: html, css

Ok, now, I invented `tf` for `table`

```
<table>
<tr>

<td><b>User Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Password</b></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<tf colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></tf>
</tr>

</table>
```

It somehow works but the `tf` row jump on top.

**How to fix?**

Comment: LOL, you really can't just create your own tags Tom... that's not how code works.

Comment: Well, actually if you use [Web Components](http://webcomponents.org/) or its polyfill [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), you can

Comment: @methyl: Yes, but that’s not what this is …

Comment: _“How to fix?”_ – write proper HTML, instead of trying to invent your own. If you described what you actually want to _achieve_ here, we can perhaps help you with that.

Comment: _If_ you are perhaps looking for a possibility to structure content in your table in a more meaningful way (is `tf` supposed to mean a “table footer” in some way?) – then look into `thead`, `tbody`  and `tfoot` elements. // And seeing as this seems to be a login form only, and not to be actually displaying _tabular_ data – look into layout techniques that do not abuse tables for layout purposes, that is “out” since about a decade.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not one of them but there are proponents of using tables for form layout as, in effect, it is a *table* of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just **invent** new tags and expect the browser to know what to do.

Besides from that, I believe you are looking for a proper utilization of the `tfoot` tag, like it is described here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

So what you want to do is:

```
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>User Name</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Password</b></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

This simply happens because the `<table>` tag does not recognize `<tf>`. `<td>` and `<tr>` are tags that link to the table tag which is why they appear correctly. The only way to use unrelated tags are within the `<td>` tags.

The unrelated tag `<tf>` gets thrown out of the table because of this and this is why it is shown above the table